# Using row-wise column indices in a vector to extract values from data frame

Tags: r

Using vector of column positional indexes such as:

```
> i <- c(3,1,2)
```

How can I use the index to extract the 3rd value from the first row of a data frame, the 1st value from the second row, the 2nd value from the third row, etc.

For example, using the above index and:

```
> dframe <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"), y=c("d","e","f"), z=c("g","h","i"))

> dframe  
  x y z  
1 a d g  
2 b e h  
3 c f i
```

I would like to return:

```
> [1] "g", "b", "f"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use matrix indexing, like this:

```
dframe[cbind(seq_along(i), i)]
# [1] "g" "b" "f"
```

The `cbind(seq_along(i), i)` part creates a two column matrix of the relevant row and column that you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Df <- data.frame(
  x=c("a","b","c"), 
  y=c("d","e","f"), 
  z=c("g","h","i"))
##
i <- c(3,1,2)
##
index2D <- function(v = i, DF = Df){
  sapply(1:length(v), function(X){
    DF[X,v[X]]
  })
}
##
> index2D()
[1] "g" "b" "f"
```