# R: Why can't data.frame() create variables dependent on other variables it creates?

Tags: r, dataframe, object, scope, environment

When creating data frames with multiple variables using the `data.frame()` function, each variable
cannot be a function of other variables generated within `data.frame()`. This is demonstrated in the code sample below, where Example 1 succeeds because the expressions for `x` and `y` don't require any object in our environment and Example 2 returns an error because `x` is not in the global environment.

**Why does this happen?**

I can think of two possible explanations, but I do not know how to evaluate them (pun intended):

- **Scoping**: each assignment expression is evaluated sequentially (i.e. `x` is assigned then `y` is assigned) but only looks for objects in the environment in which `data.frame()` was called. Since `data.frame()` was called in the global environment but `x` is not in the global environment, an error is returned in Example 2. This may also be why `y = 6` rather than `y = 1` in Example 3.
- **Evaluation**: all assignment expressions are evaluated simultaneously (i.e. in parallel), causing `x` to not exist in *any* environment at the time `y` is assigned a value that is a function of `x`. While R employs lexical (i.e. static) scoping, perhaps `data.frame()` is designed to look for `x` in both the environment in which `x` was called and the child environments within the function.

```r
# Example 1 (success)
data.frame(x = 0, y = 0 + 1)
#>   x y
#> 1 0 1

# Example 2 (failure)
data.frame(x = 0, y = x + 1)
#> Error in data.frame(x = 0, y = x + 1): object 'x' not found

# Example 3
x <- 5
data.frame(x = 0, y = x + 1)
#>   x y
#> 1 0 6
```

**Note**: I am trying to understand why `data.frame()` exhibits this behavior. As observed in the comments and demonstrated below, `tibble::tibble()` is an excellent option for users who wish to generate variables in a `data.frame` conditional on other variables in the `data.frame`.

```r
library(tibble)

# Tibble Example 1: y uses x!
tibble(x = 0, y = x + 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     1

# Tibble Example 2: y uses x, ignoring the global x!
x <- 5
tibble(x = 0, y = x + 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     1
```

Comment: You could instead use `tibble`, then this works `tibble(x = 0, y = x + 1)`

Comment: The reason this does not work with `data.frame` is R's lazy-evaluation (`tibble` knows the "order" of the arguments, and evaulates them in the order passed, whereas `data.frame` columns even cannot access the scope of the dataframe itself) - so a combination of both

Comment: Yes, I know this.  I've added an explanation clarifying my intent with the post and showing tibble's functionality.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not sure about the lazy evaluation point...is there a way to demonstrate that data.frame() is using lazy evaluation? I know tibble does, but it only "fixes" this issue because it evaluates sequentially https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/tibble

Comment: Could you clarify what *specifically* you are hoping to get in an answer. It was already pointed out that one of the key differences between the `data.frame` and `tibble` constructors is the fact that `tibble` builds columns sequentially, whereas `data.frame` does not. What additional details/information are you looking for? I feel it is going to be difficult to satisfactorily address a question of the form "why is this so".

Comment: You may have already come across this post but if not this may be interesting & relevant: [What can a data frame do that a tibble cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466656/what-can-a-data-frame-do-that-a-tibble-cannot)

Comment: Not really an answer to "why" `data.frame` does things the way it does, but the [source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L437) shows "what" the `data.frame` constructor does. From a quick/superficial look, `data.frame` simply iterates through the list of all (column) vectors, does some dimension checking & recycling (if necessary), and then stores them in a dressed `list`, i.e. your final `data.frame`. This is just a simple `for` loop, and processing element *i* has no reference to element *i-1*.

Comment: @MauritsEvers A satisfactory answer would show that `data.frame()` internally is doing something where arguments are evaluated "simultaneously" (presumably via vectorization since nothing is parallelized in base R) so this cannot happen and/or where it is evaluating objects in the scope of the call rather than within. I have zero interest in what `tibble()` does (not) do and only added that note for those who might find this question with the hope of finding something with the documented behavior of `tibble()`.

Comment: @user3614648 `data.frame()` does *not* evaluate "simultaneously". Quite the contrary. It processes *sequentially*, but there is no eval. It's just a simple `for` loop (please take a look at my previous comment and the link to the `data.frame` constructor source code!). It's not clear to me what more you're after. The source code shows you exactly what's going on. There is no "magic" there, no (lazy) eval, no quotation.